# Using async await when mapping over an arrays values

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to use the new async/await in conjunction with mapping over an array of values.
However I am a bit confused, which should have the await keyword infront of it, in this specific scenario.

There isnt much information regarding this topic yet.

I am trying to simply `map()` over and array of values, which are used in an Axios `get()` request, which then returns a `then()` value, which gets added to the array returned by the `map()` function.

This is my code right now:

```
async function get_prices (arrayOfDates, crypto, FIAT) {
  // I tried this way (return value can be found below)
  let arry_of_prices = arrayOfDates.map(async function(date){
    let a = await fetch_data(date, crypto, FIAT)
    return a
  });

  // And this way (return value can be found below)
  let arry_of_prices = await arrayOfDates.map(date => fetch_data(date, crypto, FIAT));
} 

const fetch_data = (timestamp, crypto, FIAT) => {
  axios.get(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricehistorical?fsym=${crypto}&tsyms=${FIAT}&ts=${timestamp}`)
  .then(function (response) {
    return Object.values(response.data).map(key => Object.values(key))[0][0]
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

let arr = [1468965600, 1469052000, 1469138400,1469484000]

get_prices(arr, "BTC", "USD").then(arr => console.log(arr))
```

The first try returned 4 `resolved` promises, but the values were `undefined`.
Whereas the second return an array with 4 `undefined`.

Does anyone have an idea of how this could be structured, so that the `map()` waits until the function is resolved and then adds the value to the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` doesn't know anything about promises, so when you use an `async` callback with `map`, you'll get an array of promises, not values. If you then want a promise that will resolve when all of those promises have resolved, you can use `Promise.all`.

However, in your case, you don't need an async function, since you're using `fetch_data` in the callback. You need to modify `fetch_data` so it *returns* the promise from `axios.get` (and remove the `catch` handler):

```
const fetch_data = (timestamp, crypto, FIAT) => {
  return axios.get(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricehistorical?fsym=${crypto}&tsyms=${FIAT}&ts=${timestamp}`)
  .then(function (response) {
    return Object.values(response.data).map(key => Object.values(key))[0][0]
  });
}
```

(This is one of the rules of promises: If you're returning the promise, you don't handle rejections from it [unless you want to convert them into different rejections, or if you can usefully convert them to resolutions instead]. If you *don't* return the promise, you *do* handle rejections.)

Now you already have a promise, so you use that in the `map` (no need for `async`):

```
async function get_prices (arrayOfDates, crypto, FIAT) {
  let arr_of_price_promises = arrayOfDates.map(function(date){
    let a = fetch_data(date, crypto, FIAT)
    return a
  });
  return Promise.all(arr_of_price_promises);
}
```

Notice I removed the `await` from in front of `fetch_data`. We return `fetch_data`'s promise directly, then wait for them all.

Or with an arrow function:

```
async function get_prices (arrayOfDates, crypto, FIAT) {
  let arr_of_price_promises = arrayOfDates.map(date => fetch_data(date, crypto, FIAT));
  return Promise.all(arr_of_price_promises);
}
```

Comment: But doesnt this still return a resolved promise, with undefined value?

Comment: @Jousi: No, it returns a promise that will resolve when all the `fetch` promises resolve (or reject when the first `fetch` promise rejects). It resolves with an array which is the resolved values of each of the `fetch` promises, in the order in which those promises were given to `Promise.all`.

Comment: @Jousi: Oh, sorry, you're using your own `fetch_data`, not `fetch`. You need to modify `fetch_data` a bit, I'll add that.

Comment: Yep just noticed it too, adjusted :) Thanks TJ!

Comment: @Jousi: :-) Updated the answer to show what to do to `fetch_data`. Glad that helped!