# JS, use of Async Await function in Axios when mapping over an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The function is intended to loop over an array and POST each value in the array to database. I got error if I use async await function.

Error : Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

```
 const myfunction = async () => {
    [1,2,3].map((item) => {
      
      const endpoint = "/api/";

      await apiService(endpoint, "POST", item)
        .then((r) => console.log(r))
        
    });
  };
```

*The apiservice function use browser fetch function with stored cookie*

This might be duplicate of following question [Using async await when mapping over an arrays values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266198/using-async-await-when-mapping-over-an-arrays-values), but I did not understand it.

Comment: Your apiService call is inside the map callback, which means you need to change that function to async: .map(async(item) .... )

Comment: Is the intent to just loop over the array? `.map()` might be an overkill. Can use simple `for` loop or `for (item of array) {..}`.

Comment: @ambianBeing I will use as suggested thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `await` does not occur directly in your `async` function, but in a function that is passed to `.map` (which is not `async`).

Besides, `.map` is abused here, since you do not return anything in the callback, nor use the array that `.map` returns.

Just use  a `for` loop instead:

```
const myfunction = async () => {
    for (let item of [1,2,3]) {      
        const endpoint = "/api/";
        await apiService(endpoint, "POST", item)
            .then((r) => console.log(r))
    }
}
```

Also, using `then` is an antipattern here, since `await` is actually there to *avoid* using that. So better code it like this:

```
const myfunction = async () => {
    for (let item of [1,2,3]) {      
        const endpoint = "/api/";
        let r = await apiService(endpoint, "POST", item)
        console.log(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Kudos for the clarification.

Comment: Where will I put the async key work in the above function as you suggested ?

Comment: `async` can stay where it was. For clarity I added the function wrapper that you had also in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
const myfunction =  () => {
    [1,2,3].map( async(item) => { // async should be here
      
      const endpoint = "/api/";

      await apiService(endpoint, "POST", item)
        .then((r) => console.log(r))
        
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
 const myfunction = () => {
    [1,2,3].map(async (item) => {
      
      const endpoint = "/api/";

      await apiService(endpoint, "POST", item)
        .then((r) => console.log(r))
        
    });
  };
```